# Faces messages not shown until the page is refreshed

Tags: jsf, richfaces, message

I'm using JSF1.2, Tomcat 6.0, RichFaces 3.3.3, and Java 6u31.

I do an action in the managed bean, and show a message to the user. That's OK. 
After that, I do another action in managed, and then the messages doesn't work anymore until I refresh the page.

I can assure you that the problem isn't in the managed bean, because I just removed all the method impl, leaving it empty, and the bug still happens.

So, the problem is something in the `xhtml` pages. I tried to put an `a4j:status`, but it doenst show any error.

So, I see myself without hope. I will not post all the code here, because it's too big and complex.

I wonder if one of you ever seen something like this, or if you have one guess of whats happening. I can edit the question adding any info you want.

Comment: Just create an SSCCE and update your question to include it. Surely you don't need >1000 lines of code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I can't do it because I don't have any Idea of exactly what is generating the problem. Thats because I asking you if someone ever seen something like this before, or have any tips/suggestions. Sorry about the SSCCE.

Comment: I just found that this problem is related to rich:fileupload.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solve this problem.

I has a `onupload` in the rich:fileupload.
I just remove it, and add a `a4j:support`, like this:

`<a4j:support event="onupload" oncomplete="foo()" />`

That's it. I just don't understand why it works that way, and doesnt in the old way.

BTW, thanks.